# Talend open studio for data integration

Tags: talend, insert-update

In Talent open studio. i have  to add different source file to one output table..How can i fetch the last id in that output table and generate the very next id and continue insertion with different sources

Answer (score 0):

Add a subjob prior to your current subjob.
in a tDBINPut component select your lastID through a query (select maxID , select top 1 , etc) .
Put the result in a variable (global variable or context variable), in a tJavaRow for example. (context.lastID=input_row.id)
Use this variable in a tMap to generate the next ID, through Numeric.sequence function.
In the output mapping of your tmap, you should add something like  `Numeric.sequence(context.lastID,1,1)`

I think there are plenty of solutions to get the lastID and generate a sequence from there. you can also check advanced output parameters on your tDBOutput.